# Can a derived class be marked BeforeFieldInit even if the base class cannot?

Tags: c#

In the code below, `A` cannot be marked as `BeforeFieldInit` due to the existence of my static constructor. However, I did not write a static constructor for `B`.

```
abstract class A { 
    static A(){} 
    public static object a;
}
class B : A { static object b = a; }
```

Is it possible for `B` to get marked as `BeforeFieldInit` even though its base class `A` cannot?

Comment: What happened when you tried?